# Way to get Language Description from the locale id

Tags: angular, locale

With angular, Is there a way to get the language description by passing the locale id?

Something like,

`en-CA` should return `Canadian English`

`fr-CA` should return `Canadian French`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid not. But you can use a self made mapping like this:

```
const locales = {
"af": "Afrikaans",
"sq": "Albanian",
"ar-dz": "Arabic (Algeria)",
"ar-bh": "Arabic (Bahrain)",
"ar-eg": "Arabic (Egypt)",
"ar-iq": "Arabic (Iraq)",
"ar-jo": "Arabic (Jordan)",
"ar-kw": "Arabic (Kuwait)",
"ar-lb": "Arabic (Lebanon)",
"ar-ly": "Arabic (Libya)",
"ar-ma": "Arabic (Morocco)",
"ar-om": "Arabic (Oman)",
"ar-qa": "Arabic (Qatar)",
"ar-sa": "Arabic (Saudi Arabia)",
"ar-sy": "Arabic (Syria)",
"ar-tn": "Arabic (Tunisia)",
"ar-ae": "Arabic (U.A.E.)",
"ar-ye": "Arabic (Yemen)",
"eu": "Basque",
"be": "Belarusian",
"bg": "Bulgarian",
"ca": "Catalan",
"zh-hk": "Chinese (Hong Kong)",
"zh-cn": "Chinese (PRC)",
"zh-sg": "Chinese (Singapore)",
"zh-tw": "Chinese (Taiwan)",
"hr": "Croatian",
"cs": "Czech",
"da": "Danish",
"nl-be": "Dutch (Belgium)",
"nl": "Dutch (Standard)",
"en": "English",
"en-au": "English (Australia)",
"en-bz": "English (Belize)",
"en-ca": "English (Canada)",
"en-ie": "English (Ireland)",
"en-jm": "English (Jamaica)",
"en-nz": "English (New Zealand)",
"en-za": "English (South Africa)",
"en-tt": "English (Trinidad)",
"en-gb": "English (United Kingdom)",
"en-us": "English (United States)",
"et": "Estonian",
"fo": "Faeroese",
"fa": "Farsi",
"fi": "Finnish",
"fr-be": "French (Belgium)",
"fr-ca": "French (Canada)",
"fr-lu": "French (Luxembourg)",
"fr": "French (Standard)",
"fr-ch": "French (Switzerland)",
"gd": "Gaelic (Scotland)",
"de-at": "German (Austria)",
"de-li": "German (Liechtenstein)",
"de-lu": "German (Luxembourg)",
"de": "German (Standard)",
"de-ch": "German (Switzerland)",
"el": "Greek",
"he": "Hebrew",
"hi": "Hindi",
"hu": "Hungarian",
"is": "Icelandic",
"id": "Indonesian",
"ga": "Irish",
"it": "Italian (Standard)",
"it-ch": "Italian (Switzerland)",
"ja": "Japanese",
"ko": "Korean",
"ku": "Kurdish",
"lv": "Latvian",
"lt": "Lithuanian",
"mk": "Macedonian (FYROM)",
"ml": "Malayalam",
"ms": "Malaysian",
"mt": "Maltese",
"no": "Norwegian",
"nb": "Norwegian (Bokmål)",
"nn": "Norwegian (Nynorsk)",
"pl": "Polish",
"pt-br": "Portuguese (Brazil)",
"pt": "Portuguese (Portugal)",
"pa": "Punjabi",
"rm": "Rhaeto-Romanic",
"ro": "Romanian",
"ro-md": "Romanian (Republic of Moldova)",
"ru": "Russian",
"ru-md": "Russian (Republic of Moldova)",
"sr": "Serbian",
"sk": "Slovak",
"sl": "Slovenian",
"sb": "Sorbian",
"es-ar": "Spanish (Argentina)",
"es-bo": "Spanish (Bolivia)",
"es-cl": "Spanish (Chile)",
"es-co": "Spanish (Colombia)",
"es-cr": "Spanish (Costa Rica)",
"es-do": "Spanish (Dominican Republic)",
"es-ec": "Spanish (Ecuador)",
"es-sv": "Spanish (El Salvador)",
"es-gt": "Spanish (Guatemala)",
"es-hn": "Spanish (Honduras)",
"es-mx": "Spanish (Mexico)",
"es-ni": "Spanish (Nicaragua)",
"es-pa": "Spanish (Panama)",
"es-py": "Spanish (Paraguay)",
"es-pe": "Spanish (Peru)",
"es-pr": "Spanish (Puerto Rico)",
"es": "Spanish (Spain)",
"es-uy": "Spanish (Uruguay)",
"es-ve": "Spanish (Venezuela)",
"sv": "Swedish",
"sv-fi": "Swedish (Finland)",
"th": "Thai",
"ts": "Tsonga",
"tn": "Tswana",
"tr": "Turkish",
"uk": "Ukrainian",
"ur": "Urdu",
"ve": "Venda",
"vi": "Vietnamese",
"cy": "Welsh",
"xh": "Xhosa",
"ji": "Yiddish",
"zu": "Zulu"
}

console.info(locales['en-CA']);
```